# To check that if this inequality is an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: inequality, relations, equivalence-relations

I proved this inequality ;

Which is a relation on $\mathbb{Z}$ s.t a and b belongs to $\mathbb{Z}$

$$a^2 - b^2 \le 7$$

is reflexive ,
 I'm stuck at the symmetry of this relation, can anyone help?
Thank you so much!

Comment: Your question is unreadable.  What is the relation?  Who is Abraham?

Comment: Are you sure this defines an equivalence relation?

Comment: I'm so sorry , I just edited it

Comment: No we have to check and see if it is , thank you @P-addict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relation is not symmetric. For example we have for $a=0$ and $b=3$:

$a^2-b^2 =-9 \le 7$, but $b^2-a^2=9 > 7.$

Comment: yes, thank you sir , but how can we prove that for all Z ?, without giving an example

Comment: He proved that it is NOT an equivalence relation. One counterexample is enough, you don't need to prove it for all $a, b \in \mathbb{Z} $.

Comment: oh thank you so much @cavallorosso